# After entering the correct login password i am getting enter password screen again

Tags: boot, dual-boot, login, password

I have dual booted Ubuntu 20.04 on my HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC. 1st day it worked fine. Today, after giving my login password , the circle beside it rotated once and the same login screen came again. This was the 2nd time it happened in a week. 3 days back when i dual booted Ubuntu 20.04, this problem occured. I thought it was a generic error and deleted the OS and installed it again. But now i face the problem one more time.

Please see the video i recorded in the link "https://youtu.be/sTexC9Ro8W4" for the detailed explanation of the isssue. Please help.

Comment: I recall the followin post helped me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership

Answer (score 0):

It can be the same issue I had

First, go to tty3 (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>) and login
`sudo adduser test`

Go back in the login shell and try to log as the test user. It may be useful to know if it is user dependent.

Here few fix you can try on tty3 (and don't forget if there's something usefull on `.xsession-errors` file in `~/` and edit your question with it)

---

In `~/`, run
`ls -lah | grep -i Xauthority`
If .Xauthority permission are'nt yours, resolve it with `sudo chown username:username .Xauthority`

---

`ls -lah /tmp`
you should get that line
`drwxrwxrwt 22 root      root      132K May 25 13:07 .`
If you get anything else that `drwxrwxrwt`, here's your issue and you need to run `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`

---

Make sure you're connected to the internet (`ping 8.8.8.8`)

`sudo apt install lightdm` and reboot on lightdm.

Once logged your session, `sudo apt --configure gdm3`. [In my case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1240763/login-loop-for-user-account-gdm3), it didn't work so I made lightdm, then choose gdm3 in the menu. It's just a workaround. You might also try to purge gdm3 and install it back, as I did.

---

In my case, gdm3 still was broken, althought I could log in the test user... I didn't find how, and I still use lightdm instead. You would be kind if you update your question with every piece of information so that it'll help every users in that situation (including me :p ).